# Conditionally stop displaying the org.eclipse.ui.newWizard

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I have created a new wizard using `org.eclipse.ui.newWizard` extension point.
It creates a new file under selected package.

Now I need to show an error message and **Not to show the wizard** if the user doesn't select a package. My `getSelectedPackage()` method returns the currunt package if selected, if not returns `null`.

Everything is working as expected except `performCancel()`. It is showing the error message and then the wizard dialog as well.

Can anyone suggest me how to conditionally stop displaying the wizard?

```
public class NewTestScriptWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {

public NewTestScriptWizard() {
    super();
    setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
    if(getSelectedPackage()== null){
        MessageDialog
                .openError(getShell(), "Error","You must select a package to create a new file");
    performCancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop the wizard creation at this point. `performCancel` does nothing when called like this.

The only thing to do is display an error message in the first page of the wizard (with `setMessage` or `setErrorMessage`) and set the page to be incomplete (with `setPageComplete(false)` so that only cancel can be pressed.

Comment: Thanks @greg for your comment as always!